# Is there a way to find a specific word multiple times, then find related words near that word?

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have the below and I am looking for a way to find the word "pizza" as many times no matter how many words are in between.

Then find related words (e.g. pepperoni, large) only if NEAR the word "pizza"

I tried using a larger character count on f1 {0,100} but it seems to carry over and ignore the {0,50} I have for near words

```
import re

string = ['I need a pizza with pepperoni word word word word word word word and a small pizza']

for s in string:
    f1 = re.findall(r'(\b(pizza|pie|pizzeria)\b)',s, re.IGNORECASE)
    if f1:

        f2 = re.findall(r'(.{0,50}\b(pepperoni|cheese|sausage)\b.{0,50})',f1[0][0], re.IGNORECASE)
        if f2:
            print("what size?")

        f3 = re.findall(r'(.{0,50}\b(small|medium|large)\b.{0,50})',f1[0][0], re.IGNORECASE)
        if f3:
            print("what toppings?")

        if not f2 and not f3:
            print("what size and toppings?")
```

Comment: Not much of what you are doing here makes sense. `for s in string` is just going to iterate once, so it's superfluous. `f1` is just going to contain: `[('pizza', 'pizza'), ('pizza', 'pizza')]` so searching each string in that list of tuples for things like `pepperoni` and whatnot is going to fail. I feel like regex may be the wrong direction for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: for example, I'm trying to find if the word "large" if near the word pizza by finding pizza 1st, then NEAR word "large", "pepperoni" etc. And not have it match things like "**Large** Soda" which would be out of the character range I specify.

Comment: I hear you. I just think that the approach to solve it is wrong, going in all in with `findall()`. For instance, your `findall()` will find two instances of the word `pizza`, right? But... how do you search around each instance. You don't know where in the original string each instance occurs because `findall()` doesn't tell you their position, just that there are two of them that exist in the string. Instead `for i in range(0, len(string[0].split())): if string[0].split()[i] == 'pizza':` will tell you that `i` is the position of the word in the string so you can search around it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "for i in range" , but yes that seems to be what I need! to search near the specific word

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment. Consider a direction like so:

```
string = ['I need a pizza with pepperoni word word word word word word word and a small pizza']

for sentence in string:
    string_list = sentence.split()
    for i in range(0, len(string_list)):
        if string_list[i] == 'pizza':  
            #We found the word "pizza" and it's at position `i` in the string. So you can search around `i-2:i+2` (to search two words before and two words after) for the rest of your terms.
```

Going this route you have more information to act on when `pizza` is found in the string. You'll have more work to do to clean this up. For instance, `i-2` and `i+2` may be outside the bounds of the sentence (there will be no words at position -1 or 18, for instance). At any rate, this should get you going in a positive direction.